# Is my usage of the word “forthcoming” correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I truly appreciate your forthcoming 
by bringing to my notice about the noise I am causing.

or

I truly appreciate you forthcoming 
by bringing to my notice about the noise I am causing.

Comment: "Is my use correct?" not "does ...is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is ungrammatical in a couple of respects.

**forthcoming** is an adjective that means "candid". So you would have to say

> I appreciate you *being* forthcoming

or

> I appreciate that you *were* forthcoming

Second, we "bring *something* to someone's notice".    **bring** is a transitive verb that has a direct object, and thus the prepositional phrase "about the noise" is wrong.

> ... by bringing  the noise I was making to my notice
>
> ... by bringing to my notice the noise I was making

Answer (score 1):

Forthcoming has various meanings none of which make sense here. I think you mean 'coming forward'.  You could say "I truly appreciate your coming forward and bringing the noise I am causing to my notice."